# DeleteFile() failing but the file is there (very long file name)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, delete-file

I'm writing a backup program that is having errors. Stepping through the code with a debugger, I'm finding I'm getting errors deleting files.

I'm using `CFileFind` to locate the files, and I use `CFileFind::GetFilePath()` to obtain the full path name.

```
CFileFind find;
BOOL bContinue = find.FindFile(AppendPath(lpszPath, _T("*")));
while (bContinue)
{
    bContinue = find.FindNextFile();
    if (!find.IsDirectory())
    {
        if (find.IsReadOnly())
            ClearReadOnlyAttribute(find);
        if (!::DeleteFile(find.GetFilePath()))
            return false;
    }
}
```

`DeleteFile()` is returning `FALSE`, and `GetLastError()` is returning 3 (`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`), and was in other cases returning 2 (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`).

As you can see, I first attempt to remove the read-only attribute if it is set; however, I can see that the file exists and it does not have the read-only attribute.

One thing to note is that the file name is very long. This code has actually been tested and working pretty well with shorter filenames. In this case, `find.GetFilePath()` returns:

> \\Readyshare\USB 3\Backups\DRIVEZ_BACKUP\Stacey\Backup 0001\Music\TO BE DELETED\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music\Dave Matthews Band\Away from the World (Deluxe Version)\Away from the World (Deluxe Version.itlp\audio\DaveMatthewsBand_AwayFromTheWorld_backgroundaudio.m4a

And this looks correct. If I copy all but the filename into Windows Explorer, it shows me that folder. And the file exists there in that folder.

Does anyone know why `DeleteFile()` would tell me the path or file does not exist when in fact it does?

**UPDATE:**

Based on Bruno Ferreira's answer, I'm running my filenames through the following method. (Sorry for the old CString-style code, I'm updating an older MFC program.)

```
CString CBackupWorker::ConvertToExtendedLengthPath(LPCTSTR pszPath)
{
    CString s(pszPath);

    if (s.GetLength() >= MAX_PATH)
    {
        if (::isalpha(s[0]) && s[1] == ':')
        {
            s.Insert(0, _T("\\\\?\\"));
        }
        else if (s[0] == '\\' && s[1] == '\\')
        {
            s.Delete(0, 2);
            s.Insert(0, _T("\\\\\?\\UNC\\"));
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

As you can see the code, prepends the appropriate prefix if the file name exceeds `MAX_PATH`. Steps are taken to append the appropriate prefix depending on whether or not the path specifies a network path.

I have no idea why it was made this incredibly messy. I really don't see a backwards compatibility issue if Windows allows you to specify a longer name. On Windows 10, there is a registry setting you can change so that this nonsense is not required. But of course, I don't want to limit my software to only tweaked versions of Windows 10.

Comment: Nice. A downvote without an explanation. That's pretty spineless. How could I possibly provide more details than I have here?

Comment: `\Readyshare\...` this is exactly path ? or may be `\\Readyshare\...` file not local ?

Comment: The path starts off with two backslashes, as I have it in my question. That is the *exact* path. It's on a USB drive that's connected to my router. And I haven't had any problems until I started getting these longer filenames because of the directory structure.

Comment: `Windows Explorer, it shows me that folder.` are backup program run in same logon session as and explorer ? who mapped` \\readyshare\`

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, I'm running the software from the same session where I'm running Windows Explorer.

Comment: Pretty sure that filename exceeds MAX_PATH.

Comment: @MrEricSir: Yes, me too. But don't know anything about `DeleteFile()` not being able to handle names that long. I am using Unicode.

Comment: @JonathanWood The filename length restriction is explicitly called out in the docs for `DeleteFile()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MrEricSir: Hmmm... it's very clear about the ANSI version, but there is another discussion related to Unicode. You might be right though. Still reading... Am I supposed to use `\\?\\\Readyshare\...`?

Comment: you need use  "\\?\UNC\Readyshare\USB 3\..."

Comment: Other potential issues. I think a Visual Studio update created a very long file name for a one time usage install file that was creating issues. There was no need for the name to be so long, so I just renamed it. Going way back, SecureRom digital rights program creates garbled file names that can't be copied and are difficult to delete. Win 10 won't allow SecureRom, and Win 7 or later require the user to enable SecureRom, so it's a legacy problem dating back to Win XP (I don't know about Win Vista).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Parameters
>
> lpFileName [in] The name of the file to be deleted. In the ANSI
>   version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH characters.
>   To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the Unicode
>   version of the function and prepend "\\?\" to the path. For more
>   information, see Naming a File.

Basically, you should call `DeleteFileW` prepending `\\?\` for local paths and `\\?\UNC\` for remote paths, something like this:

```
CFileFind find;
BOOL bContinue = find.FindFile(AppendPath(lpszPath, _T("*")));
while (bContinue)
{
    bContinue = find.FindNextFile();
    if (!find.IsDirectory())
    {
        if (find.IsReadOnly())
            ClearReadOnlyAttribute(find);

        CString path = find.GetFilePath();
        if (path.GetLength() >= MAX_PATH)
        {
            if (PathIsUNC(path)) {
                path.TrimLeft(_T("\\"));
                path.Insert(0, _T("\\\\?\\UNC\\"));
            }
            else
                path.Insert(0, _T("\\\\?\\"));
        }

        if (!::DeleteFileW(path))
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `\\?\` prefix will be worked only for local file system absolute path and not will be work for network path

Comment: @RbMm From MSDN: `The "\\?\" prefix can also be used with paths constructed according to the universal naming convention (UNC). To specify such a path using UNC, use the "\\?\UNC\" prefix. For example, "\\?\UNC\server\share", where "server" is the name of the computer and "share" is the name of the shared folder.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: this is yes - `\\?\UNC\` will be work, but in your code is `\\?\` what is wrong. really when win32 subsystem view `\\?\` prefix it simply convert it to `\??\`

Comment: in case UNC path need remove two forward backsplash \\ before append \\?\UNC\

Comment: [PathIsUNC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773712.aspx) is restricted to path names of maximum length `MAX_PATH`. Unless the documentation is wrong, this code is.

Comment: @IInspectable I might be wrong, but `PathIsUNC` ignore the rest of the string should the beginning of it matches...

Comment: Even if you are right, this is neither part of the documented contract, nor does it help in situations, where the UNC prefix and server part exceed `MAX_PATH` characters.